# Add "loops" together? Convert into hours and/or minutes

Tags: python, python-3.4

My question is how I'd be able to add the minutes and calculate them into hours and minutes.

Here some code that I have:

```
import math

def main():   

    total = 0
    for i in range (number):
        task = int(input('How many minutes will this task take? '))
        print(task)
        total += task
    print(total)
    hour = total // 60
    minute = hour % 0
    print('Hour(s): ', hour, 'Minute(s): ', minute)

main()
```

Comment: Do you know how to convert from a number representing minutes, to two numbers representing hours and minutes? On paper for example? Say you have the number 146, how many hours are in there, and ho many minutes remaining?

Comment: @MartijnPieters 146 minutes would be 2 hours and 26 minutes, I believe.

Comment: So how would you go about calculating that if the number was instead written down as `x`?

Comment: @MartijnPieters So `x  = 146`? Then I guess 146 divided by 60 which would be 2 hours and then the minutes would be the remainder; 26 minutes

Comment: Do you think you can code that up in Python? There are [several arithmetic operators](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations) you could use here. Division and remainder are both among them, if you read the documentation carefully you may even find **one** function that can do the job here.

Comment: A gentler overview could be the [*Using Python as a Calculator* section of the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#using-python-as-a-calculator).

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'll try but the program asks how many tasks you want to do and then I think it should add those together.  I'm pretty sure I know what to do afterwards.

Comment: You already have a loop working, and you already have numeric input working. I gave you the tools to do arithmetic, so why not try and see if you can add up the numbers in that loop you already have?

Comment: The reason I focused on the method to go from minutes to hours and minutes is because that is basically the only part you appeared to be missing here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'll go ahead and try.  I'll get back to you on it.

Comment: Do you want to print the total duration of all the tasks, or do you want to print the clock time that the last task finishes?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I got it to either print minutes or hours not both or add them together.  For instance I would type in 2 tasks.  Then 30 minutes then 40 minutes.  The output would be: 'Hour(s): 0 Minute(s): 40' instead of 'Hour(s): 1 Minute(s): 10'

Comment: total duration @PM2Ring

Comment: @MaxSedor: now we are getting to a point we can help you. Please update your question with the code you have so far, the input you give it, the output you expected and what you got instead.

Comment: I accidentally deleted it, but I'll go ahead and do it again. @MartijnPieters

Comment: Your loop needs to add up the number of minutes entered for each task. You can do that by doing `total = 0` before the start of the loop, and then inside the loop do `total = total + task`; a more compact way to write that is `total += task`

Comment: Thanks for that @PM2Ring I totally forgot about '+=' It now adds them and is just fine with hours, however minutes is not really doing anything...

Comment: @MartijnPieters edited the code just need to fix the % part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are *almost there*. Your calculation method is also incorrect; you want the remainder of `total` and `60`, not of `hours` and `0`:

```
hour = total // 60
minute = total % 60
```

The remainder of `hour` and `0` is always going give you a `ZeroDivisionError` as you cannot divide by 0.

The [`divmod()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod) can give you both the hours and the minutes in *one step*:

```
hour, minute = divmod(total, 60)
```

Comment: Oh, it most of done that b/c in the code it's inside.

Comment: @MaxSedor: perhaps fix that part of your code then? You also forgot to give us some sample input, the output you expected and what you got instead.

Comment: I'll add that, once I edit.  I'll get back to you soon as possible!

Comment: @MaxSedor: your version will give you an error message. Always include the full traceback for such errors (so starting with `Traceback (most recent call last)`).

Comment: Thank you soo much!  It worked!!  I typed in 400 minutes then 300 and it added them together to make 700 minutes.  Then gave me 11 hours and 40 minutes! Thanks so much!  It took me so long to do this and I owe to both of you!!! @MartijnPieters

Comment: @MaxSedor: I rolled back your last edit; leaving the actual problem you had in place. That way your question is useful to others in the future. The only thing I ask of you then is to *add in your input and expected output*, as well as the error you got. That way people with the same type of error can find the question and get help too.

Comment: Definitely helped me out! I think I edited it so I shows my sample input and output. @MartijnPieters

Comment: @MaxSedor: you did, but you missed out the actual output (e.g. your error).

Comment: Oh, I'll put that afterwards? Saying something like this what happened before? @MartijnPieters

Comment: @MaxSedor: Your code, as you finally posted (with the indentation fixed) would lead to a `ZeroDivision` error; you cannot use `% 0` and not get that error.

Comment: Fixed it (I think) @MartijnPieters I might have many future questions, too.  But of course, I'll do research and stuff before posting.

Comment: Not quite, as now you appear to have working code :-). I'll leave it be, I was mostly trying to teach you how Stack Overflow is supposed to work for these kinds of questions; you post your work with enough info for us to troubleshoot and correct.

Comment: Thanks again though!  Now I'll be able to add to the program without any future problems (hopefully)!  If I have any questions I'll come here after searching long and hard. @MartijnPieters  Obviously you can tell I'm new to this.

Comment: I added something when it asks you when you'll start (on the 24-hour clock) that if you enter a number bigger than 24 it asks you to try again, however if you enter the same number or a bigger number it continues on to minutes.  It works the same way for minutes too.  I'm asking how would I change it so it would keep asking you for a right value if you keep messing up?  This is what I currently have:

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response

Comment: Tried it and it's saying some of the syntax on there in python 3.4 is invalid @MartijnPieters

Comment: @MaxSedor: then perhaps you need to post a new question; but take into account that the code *as posted in that answer* works just fine under Python 3.4.

Comment: I've taken a break from it for a little bit. @MartijnPieters